# Convert VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservations to VNDetectedObjectObservation

Tags: swift, yolo, coreml, yolov5, apple-vision

I have exported YOLOV5 model, but the output configuration is in `VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservations` instead of `VNDetectedObjectObservation`.

Output configuration:

> [<VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation: 0x282f19980>
> 4FC4A8B2-A967-4CC7-8A86-E16863258F1B requestRevision=1
> confidence=1.000000 "2308" - "MultiArray : Float32 1 x 3 x 20 x 20 x 85 array" (1.000000), <VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation: 0x282f18a20>
> DA7269E9-BE2D-4A50-B5F9-99D3153CB0E7 requestRevision=1
> confidence=1.000000 "2327" - "MultiArray : Float32 1 x 3 x 40 x 40 x 85 array" (1.000000), <VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation: 0x282f18c60>
> 88211394-85CE-492E-81FC-5639E82B3416 requestRevision=1
> confidence=1.000000 "2346" - "MultiArray : Float32 1 x 3 x 80 x 80 x 85 array" (1.000000)]

So, my question is what information does this `VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation` MultiArray hold (is it something like a UIImage or CGRect?, or something different?) and how can I convert this Multidimensional Array into a useful set of data that I can actually use?

Comment: Where you able to access the Multiarray and make it usable. I am facing similar issue with RetinaFace

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn your YOLO model into a pipeline that has a NMS module at the end. Now Core ML / Vision will treat the model as an object detector.

See also my blog post: https://machinethink.net/blog/mobilenet-ssdlite-coreml/